# Django truncatewords and shows the searched word

Tags: python, django

I have a variable `sentences` contains:

"Page's web crawler began exploring the web in March 1996, with Page's own Stanford home page serving as the only starting point. To convert the backlink data that it gathered for a given web page into a measure of importance, Brin and Page developed the PageRank algorithm. While analyzing BackRub's output which, for a given URL, consisted of a list of backlinks ranked by importance the pair realized that a search engine based on PageRank would produce better results than existing techniques (existing search engines at the time essentially ranked results according to how many times the search term appeared on a page)."

Then, I use truncatewords in Django HTML to short the view of the sentences.

```
{{ sentences|truncatewords:30 }}
```

So, the result shows this:

"Page's web crawler began exploring the web in March 1996, with Page's own Stanford home page serving as the only starting point. To convert the backlink data that it . . ."

Actually, I want to show the `truncatewords` result with a specific word, for example, "BackRub", so the result supposed to be:

"While analyzing BackRub's output which, for a given URL, consisted of a list of backlinks ranked by importance the pair realized that a search engine based on PageRank would produce . . ."

Are there any solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should [write your own template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) to solve this problem.

You can get the beginning of the sentence which contains a specific word and return string starting from there. Then you can truncate result as you did above. I believe it's not the best solution. But I think it's something that you can start with. See code and results below:

#### somewhere in templatetags

```
import re

from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def findsentencebyword(sentence, word):
    matches = re.search("([^.]*?" + word + ".*)", sentence)

    if not matches:
        return sentence

    return matches.group()
```

#### then load and use it in your template like below

```
{% load <templatetag> %}

{{ sentences|findsentencebyword:"BackRub"|truncatewords:30 }}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It works. Unfortunately, this filter causes the page to become slow to load the results. Hope there has any alternative. Overall, thanks for the option.

Comment: @SamudraAjriKifli it's because of regular expression